# how can i get redirected from component to another by using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to get redirected from a component to another using a onClick in a button and yet i tried a lot of things nothing works
last thing i tried was the useHistory and push but maybe i'm using it wrong i don't know the prooblem so here's the code i tried

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import"./home.css";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
{/*this is where i called my useHistory object*/}
const history = useHistory();
return (
<React.Fragment>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
         <div className="container-fluid">
            <i className="fas fa-paw fa-2x"></i>
            <NavLink className="navbar-brand " to="/" >Pets Forever</NavLink>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto"> 
                    <li className="nav-item" >
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">About Us</NavLink>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact Us</NavLink>

                    </li>
                     
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</NavLink>

                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/signUp">Sign Up</NavLink>
                    </li>
            
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

   <div className="head-div">
            <h1>Hi there!</h1>
            <h1>Do you want buy me a toy?</h1>
            <br/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, quia?</p>
            <p>Excepturi atque possimus quas qui temporibus ratione</p>  
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={()=>{this.history.push("/login") }
 }>Shop Now</button>
    


        </div> 
</React.Fragment> 

);
}

export default Home;
```

this is also my app.jsx file i've edited the question so that to see all the code written

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './home';
import {BrowserRouter , Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import Login from './login';
import Register from './createAccount';
import About from './about';
import Contact from './contact';


import"./app.css";



class App extends React.Component {
render() { 
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/signUp" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />



            </Routes>
         </BrowserRouter>
        
    </React.Fragment>
    
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try this: `onClick={() => history.push("/login")}`. [**> Docs**](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Firstly, remove **this** from `onClick={() => this.history.push("/login")}`, and secondly, did you set routes for this application, because without it you cannot redirect?

Comment: i use routes in the app.jsx

Comment: i got this error export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useHistory` isn't in React-router-dom v6, it was in v5, so remove it completely from your code and use `useNavigate` instead.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

You have to actually create those urls in `app.js` or your main js file.
You will need to use `<Routes/>` tag.

so it can be something like this

```
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path="login" element={</login>} />
      <Route path="signUp" element={</signUp>} />
      <Route path="contact" element={</contact>} />
      <Route path="about" element={<about/>} />
    </Routes>
```

Also, wrap your `index.js` file with `<BrowserRouter/>` tags
Remove the  from App.js completely

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And now your `NavLink` will work and navigate to those components we mentioned above.

For the button to redirect you the `/login` you will import `useNaviagate` from `react-router-dom` then initialize it inside your function

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
```

on your button `onClick` , you have to call navigate function with the desired destination like this

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => navigate("/login")}/>Shop Now</button>
```

check this for more info about `Navigation` in v6. [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

Comment: already have these in app.jsx

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal you dont need history at all in your case btw.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal can you share your `app.js` code ?

Comment: done post edited and app.jsx added

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal try wrap the `index.js` file rendered tags in `<BrowserRouter>`
Like this 
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal and remove <BrowserRouter> from App.js completely

Comment: same error :"D happens

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal what error do you get ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal please check my answer, I edited it.

Comment: okay the problem is that i can't use routes to route me to another component when i'm in onClick of a button you understand what am tryin to say?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal I update the answer, please recheck and focus on the last part.
You need to use `useNavigate` instead of `usehistory` to redirect to another url

Comment: thanks a lot now it's solved <3